# Glossaries: display only long part of acronym in section headline?

Tags: glossaries

In a report that I am creating I'm sometimes using acronyms in section and chapter headlines. I'm using the `glossaries` package for this purpose.

I don't want `glossaries` to print the acronym's definition in the table of contents. Thus I'd like to use a command to print only the long version of the acronym in the section/chapter headlines, similar to the `\acl` command from the `acronym` package. I don't like the thought of manually writing the long version in every corresponding headline.

Is there such a command or another suitable way to achieve this? Or is there a way for `glossaries` to determine if it's used in a headline and just print the long version there?

//edit: `\acrlong` and `\acrshort` work pretty well. But they do two things in addition that I'd like to avoid:

1. the usage of the acronym appears in the number list in the glossary
2. a hyperref is created in the headline

Is there a way to get the long part without a hyperref and hide its usage in the `\printglossary` output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\glsentrylong` or `\Glsentrylong`. However, be careful with `\Glsentrylong` as it isn't expandable, so it can't be used in the pdf bookmarks. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides dummy text

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{\glsentrylong{sa}}

\lipsum

First use: \gls{sa}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `\Glsentrylong` in captions but make `\glsentrylong` the pdf bookmark?